# Onclick change iframe height and div position

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick, height

I want to do iframe preview of my websites. Something like themeforest have (top navbar + iframe).

I have #header-bar with height 50px and iframe with rest of a page. For it I have this fully working jquery:

```
$('#demo').height( $(window).height() - 50 );
```

I want to add `close button` to header-bar, and its function will be: `onclick` change position of header-bar from absolute top 0 to absolute top -50 and with that iframe change height to full 100%.

I am trying to use this script, but it doesn't work, i don't know the reason.

```
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
  $('#header-bar').css('top', - 50 );
  $('#demo').height( $(window).height() - 0 );
});
```

Help me with it please AND HOW I CAN ANIMATE IT WITH JS (not with css)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with syntax?
Try

```
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
    $('#header-bar').css('top', '-50px' );
    $('#demo').height( $(window).height() - 0 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery animate or fadeOut if you want to hide, check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

```
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
      //$('#header-bar').animate( {}, 1000);
      $('#header-bar').fadeOut('slow' );            
      $('#demo').height( $(window).height() - 0 );
 });
```

Hope this helps.